# Communications link failure when I connect to MySQL database using D2RQ library

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, remote-access, d2rq

I have a question:

I have a web service which runs on a virtual machine located on a remote server with Ubuntu 12.04 operating system.

Now, I want to test this Web Service and I'm using this code that I have developed in my Web Service Client:

```
public class Client3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] inputFile;
        String nomeFile;

        String jdbcURL = "jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/mydb";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "xxx";
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

        String result = wsmethod(jdbcURL, username, password, driver);

    private static String wsmethod(java.lang.String jdbcURL, java.lang.String username, java.lang.String password, java.lang.String driver) {
        ws.myWs_Service service = new ws.myWs_Service();
        ws.myWs port = service.getmyWsPort();
        return port.wsmethod(jdbcURL, username, password, driver);
    }
}
```

This code wants to pick connection information to a database and provide it to my Web Service. Then, my Web Service will use D2RQ library to convert information in the database to RDF.
My Web Service Client is created using the IP address of the virtual machine.

When I run this code, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Database connection to jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/mydb failed (user: root): Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server. (E54)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:178)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:125)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:135)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.wsmethod(Unknown Source)
    at client3.Client3.wsmethod(Client3.java:77)
    at client3.Client3.main(Client3.java:70)
Caused by: de.fuberlin.wiwiss.d2rq.D2RQException: Database connection to jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/mydb failed (user: root): Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server. (E54)
    at de.fuberlin.wiwiss.d2rq.sql.ConnectedDB.connect(ConnectedDB.java:201)
    at de.fuberlin.wiwiss.d2rq.sql.ConnectedDB.connection(ConnectedDB.java:170)
    at de.fuberlin.wiwiss.d2rq.dbschema.DatabaseSchemaInspector.<init>(DatabaseSchemaInspector.java:45)
    at de.fuberlin.wiwiss.d2rq.sql.ConnectedDB.schemaInspector(ConnectedDB.java:243)
    at de.fuberlin.wiwiss.d2rq.mapgen.MappingGenerator.<init>(MappingGenerator.java:77)
    at de.fuberlin.wiwiss.d2rq.SystemLoader.openMappingGenerator(SystemLoader.java:224)
    at Prova.classprova.methodprova(classprova.java:70)
    at WS.SmartHealth_ws.wsmethod(myWs.java:249)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor63.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver$1.invoke(InstanceResolver.java:246)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:146)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler.invoke(EndpointMethodHandler.java:257)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:95)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:629)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:588)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:573)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:470)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:295)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:515)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:285)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:143)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:155)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:189)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doPost(WSServlet.java:76)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Java Result: 1
```

I don't get this error if I run this code in local. In fact, if I create my Web Service Client using the IP address of the Web Service in local machine, I don't get this error.
Why do I get this error?

Comment: Try to 'ping' MySQL-host from your virtual machine.

Comment: ok, I get "Destination Host unreachable". Why?

Comment: This is another question that I do not know the answer.

Comment: Try to ask on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Thanks, I have asked on serverfault.com. Can anyone give me other aid?

Comment: Try to create new question with the latest details.

Comment: so, typically that new problem about the unreachable destination host is a matter of not properly bridging the host & port to the outside network from your VM.